# jQuery load various id's into sections of the page

Tags: jquery, load

In wordpress I have a page set up to pull in a random post, using jQuery I'm looking to pull in sections of this (random) page to various sections on the current (home) page at the moment the code is as below:

```
$('#wrongQuote').load('random/index.php #wrongSaying' + '?noCache=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001));
$('#sayingBy').load('random/index.php #author' + '?noCache=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001));
$('#actualQuote').load('random/index.php #actualSaying' + '?noCache=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001));
```

The trouble is this is pulling in a random #wrongSaying, #author and #actualSaying... what I need is to get random, but matching #wrongSaying / #author / #actualSaying

So I guess what I need is get this page 'random/index.php #wrongSaying' then take div#x and insert into div#a, div#f into div#e and so on...

Any ideas / help would be much appreciated!

Andy

Comment: Your code doesn't actually send the `noCache` value; the `#wrongSaying` (or other ID) should go *after* the query string.

Comment: @idealmachine - no multiple id's on the page, All good on the difference between id's/classes etc  - thanks for the point on the noCache I'll check/amend that

Comment: The query string should be a separate parameter, not concatenated to the url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with 3 requests here, I'd do the loading yourself and make **one** request to the server using [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), like this:

```
$.get('random/index.php', { noCache: Math.floor(Math.random()*10001) }, 
  function(data) {
    data = $(data);
    $('#wrongQuote').html(data.find('#wrongSaying'));
    $('#sayingBy').html(data.find('#author'));
    $('#actualQuote').html(data.find('#actualSaying'));
});
```

The fragment loading you get with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is nothing you can't do yourself...and when you're repeating the same request it's something you *shouldn't* do yourself...be efficient and make one request, with more readable code IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can load it all into a hidden element and pull out of the hidden element:

```
$(hiddenElement).load('random/index.php?noCache=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10001));

$(elementYouWanToSet).html( $(hiddenElement).find(elementYouWant) );
```

Comment: Thanks I had a similar thought but not sure its the best method? I guess sometimes dirty works..

Comment: modifying the server side code would be the clean way, but unless random/index.php is a huge file the dirty way should get the job done.

Comment: You can load it into the correct element (without a hidden element) as long as you pass `.load()` the correct ID.

Comment: Thanks @generalhenry I've got it working with using 'get' now but I will generate a random saying using php for the initial page load like you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes 3 parameters, a url, query data, and a callback function.

Try to change your lines to these:

```
var randomID = Math.floor(Math.random()*10001);
$('#wrongQuote').load('random/index.php #wrongSaying', 'noCache='+randomID);
$('#sayingBy').load('random/index.php #author', 'noCache='+randomID);
$('#actualQuote').load('random/index.php #actualSaying', 'noCache='+randomID);
```

This does not have any problem with duplicate IDs because only the ID given to `.load()` is inserted into the DOM, the rest is discarded.

Comment: Thanks, this neatens up the no cache bit but would still have the problem of hitting the page three times so getting three random parts of the saying, not matching..